# Mapping CpG Coordinate using a .bam file

Tags: r, bash, bioconductor, genetics, genome

I found a way to map the CpG position on the chicken genome, as follows:

```
library(BSgenome.Ggallus.UCSC.galGal4)
library(Biostrings)

#Create the chromossome set

chr_all=paste("chr", c(1:28, 32, "Z", "W"), sep="")

#CpG Mapping on Genome
        CpGpos<-lapply(chr_all,function(x) { 
          RES<-matchPattern("CG",Ggallus[[x]])
          RES<-cbind(rep(x,length(RES)),RES@ranges@start)
            return(RES) 
        })

        CpGpos<-do.call("rbind",CpGpos)
        CpGstartend<-cbind(CpGpos,as.numeric(CpGpos[,2])+1)
        CpGstartend<-as.data.frame(CpGstartend,stringsAsFactors=F) 
write.table(CpGstartend, "CPGstartendWGChicken.txt", sep="\t", col.names=F, row.names=T, quote=F)
```

Result:

```
[fibio@milou2 Stacks]$ cat CPGstartendWGChicken.txt |head

    1       chr1    38      39
    2       chr1    84      85
    3       chr1    146     147
```

...

Now I want to do the same with my MEDIPseq results. 
I already have the aligned sequences (BSgenome.Ggallus.UCSC.galGal4) in a .bam format to be used.

Super interesting would  be a column with coverage value for each CpG

Expected result:

```
               Chr   Start    End  Depth
               chr1    38      39    10
               chr1    84      85    12
               chr1    146     147   20
```

I know that the Bioconductor R package called MEDiPS does this, but it uses windows size. However, I need information for each CpG. 
When defining a 2bp window size, the script is killed.

Comment: It's not a bioconductor solution but I think `samtools depth` will give you Chr, Start, and Depth from a bam file, then you could use `CpGstartend %>% left_join(samtools_depth_file) -> result` via the dplyr package.

Comment: great observation, worked perfectly the first part,
But I did not understand this:
CpGstartend %>% left_join(samtools_depth_file) -> result via the dplyr package.

but to join, it will be easy now...

Comment: `left_join` is one way that the `dplyr` package can merge two data.tables. It's nice and fast for very large data.tables. It would add Depth from you samtools depth file to CpGstartend where Chr and Start match.